# C program that reads in a date and prints out the next day date

Tags: c

Hi I have just started learning C language at University. Now I am faced  with a problem I just don't know how to solve. So far we have only used 
 library and nothing else, also scanf is a topic we are going to 
learn next week. For now we just use printf for everything.
I have learned how to say if a year is a leap year or not, however, my task is the next one: Need to create a program that reads in a date and prints out the next day date with output like this:

```
Enter a date in the form day month year: 17 5 2010
The date of the next day is: 18/5/2010
```

My dilemma is that I have no idea on what operations to use or how to set the code to make sure that leap year is considered and for example if today's date is 28 2 2010 the next date needs to be 1 3 2010 because it wasn't leap year.
The only library used is  and there is no scanf yet (with scanf yet)
So far I got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int day, month, year, ndays, leapdays;
bool leapyear;
int main () {
    day = 28;
    month = 2;
    year = 2010;
    ndays = day + 1;
    leapdays = 31;
    leapyear = false;
    if (leapyear % 4 == 0) {
        leapyear = true;
    }
    if (leapyear % 100 == 0) {
        leapyear = false;
    }
    if (leapyear % 400 == 0) {
        leapyear = true;
    }
    if ((leapyear) && (month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 
         || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 )) {
        leapdays = 31;
    }
    if ((leapyear) && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 
         )) {
        leapdays = 30;
    }
    if ((leapyear) && (month == 2 )) {
        leapdays = 29;
    } else if ((leapyear == false) && (month == 2)) {
        leapdays = 28;
    }
    printf ("Enter a date in the form day month year: %d %d %d \n", day, 
             month, year);
    printf ("The date of the next day is: %d/%d/%d", ndays, month, year);
}
```

Comment: If you can't use `scanf` how do you plan on getting the input?

Comment: YOU DON'T GET INPUT, YOU JUST CREATE THE VARIABLES AND CHANGE THEM AROUND

Comment: You don't need to shout, however you do need to work on your question description since it says `Need to create a program that reads in a date` and your printf asks for input.

Comment: Your formula for figuring out if it's a leap year isn't really correct.  You may want to check into leap centuries.

Comment: I wasn't shouting, my caps lock was on sorry :)

Comment: And thanks for pointing the wrong formula out, in fact I have used the leapyear variable instead of the year variable in the brackets

Answer (score 1):

Consider a different flow.  First find the days per month first, then test if at end of month, and end of year.

```
  int year, month, day;
  // set year, month, day in some fashion

  day++;  // tomorrow

  int days_per_month = 31;
  if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    days_per_month = 30;
  } else if (month == 2) {
    days_per_month = 28;
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
      days_per_month = 29;
      if (year % 100 == 0) {
        days_per_month = 28;
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
          days_per_month = 29;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (day > days_per_month) {
    day = 1;
    month++;
    if (month > 12) {
      month = 1;
      year++;
    }
  }
```

Other improvement would use helper functions, enumerated types and various defines.  Yet this code seems to reflect OP's level.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simpler. Only check for leap year when needed.

```
int main()
{
   int Iyear, Imonth, Iday;

   Iyear = 2016;
   Imonth = 4;
   Iday = 24;

   printf ("Enter a date in the form day month year: %d %d %d \n", Iday, Imonth, Iyear);

   NextDate(&Iyear, &Imonth, &Iday);

   printf ("The date of the next day is: %d/%d/%d", Iday, Imonth, Iyear);
}

void NextDate(int *year, int *month, int *day)
{
    int daysInMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    *day = *day +1;
    if (( *month == 2 ) && (*day == 29))
    {
        // Leap year checking, if yes, Feb is 29 days.
        if(*year % 400 == 0 || (*year % 100 != 0 && *year % 4 == 0))
        {
            daysInMonth[1] = 29;
        }
    }

    if (*day > daysInMonth[*month -1])
    {
        *day = 1;
        *month = *month +1;
        if (*month > 12)
        {
            *month = 1;
            *year = *year +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add 1 to the day, check to see if that value is greater than the number of days in that month.  If so, set the day to 1 and add 1 to the month.  Then check if month is greater than 12, and if so set the month to 1 and add 1 to the year.

As for determining the number of days in a month, all months except February have the same number of days whether or not the year is a leap year.  Right now you're checking if the year is a leap year for those other months.  You can leave that check out and just check the month number.

```
if (month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 
     || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 ) {
    leapdays = 31;
}
if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    leapdays = 30;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it right :) thanks for all the help

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int day, month, year, ndays, leapdays;
    bool leapyear;
    int main () {
        day = 31;
        month = 12;
        year = 2010;
        ndays = day + 1;
        leapyear = false;
        printf ("Enter a date in the form day month year: %d %d %d \n", day, month, year);
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            leapyear = true;
        }
        if (year % 100 == 0) {
            leapyear = false;
        }
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
            leapyear = true;
        }
        if ((leapyear) && (month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 )) {
            leapdays = 31;
        }
        if ((leapyear) && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 )) {
            leapdays = 30;
        }
        if ((leapyear) && (month == 2 )) {
            leapdays = 29;
        } else if (leapyear == false) {
            leapdays = 28;
        }
        if ((leapdays == 31) && (day == 31)) {
            ndays = 1;
            month = month + 1;
        }else if ((leapdays == 30) && (day == 30)) {
                    ndays = 1;
                    month = month + 1;

        }else if ((leapdays == 29) && (day == 29)) {
                        ndays = 1;
                     month = month + 1;
        }else if ((leapdays == 28) && (day == 28)) {
                    ndays = 1;
                    month = month + 1;
        }else if ((month == 12) && (day == 31)) {
                   ndays = 1;
                    month = 1;
                   year = year + 1;
        }


        printf ("The date of the next day is: %d/%d/%d", ndays, month, year);
    }
```

Comment: You should be using functions; you should only test for a leap year if you are dealing with February; you should be using `scanf()` or similar to read the values to be processed — at the moment, you have to recompile the program to change the date.  How many days are in December, January, March, May, July, August, October in a non-leapyear?   It seems odd to have the test for leap year in `if ((leapyear) && (month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 )) { leapdays = 31; }`. Similarly for April, June, September and November?

Comment: OTOH, if you learn about `scanf()` next week, maybe you don't know about functions other than `main()` … it will be easier to write readable code when you learn to write functions.  The problems with days in the month are there regardless of whether you use functions or not.